# Get posts of a blog (xml)

Tags: swift, rss

I try to parse all posts of a blog/website into my app via an xml/rss version of the blog and display them in an UITableView. I convert the blog into xml like: `www.domain.com/feed`.
Now I only get the first 15 posts which are displayed on the first page.
If I do `www.domain.com/page/2/feed` I automatically get the xml of the first page (the link turns into `www.domain.com/feed`). Does someone knows how I could grab all posts of the blog?

Comment: Every CMS and blog system handles XML and feeds different so you definitely should add more information if you wish to get an answer for your blog.

Comment: Ok, which informations do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you gave, I presume you use Wordpress as your CMS. In order to get more powerful options to parse the blog's content, I would recommend using a JSON API plugin, for example [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/), instead of RSS.

To get the news listed on a specific page you could use a method which returns an array of dictionaries, which contains each post's data:

```
func loadAllNews(pageNumber:Int) ->[NSDictionary]  {

    url = "http://*yoursiteurl*/page/" + String(pageNumber) + "?json=1"
    var contentArray = []

    //parse url

    if let JSONData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url1)!) {

        if let json = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: [])) as? NSDictionary {

            if let reposArray = json["posts"] as? [NSDictionary] {

                for item in reposArray {

                    contentArray.append(item)

                }

            }

        }

    }

    //return fetched data

    return contentArray

}
```

If you want to get all posts, you could first parse the information about how many sites your blog has and then parse each site with the method.

Comment: Make sure you have installed and activated the plugin I recommended, and make sure you have replaced yoursiteurl with the url of your site, e. g. www.nyt.com/...

Comment: How can I implement the JSON API?

Comment: Do you use Wordpress CMS?

Comment: Yes I use Wordpress CMS

Comment: in wp-admin panel go to plugins, then click install, search for json api and install it. make sure it is the same plugin as I recommended you, otherwise it won't exactly work that way.

Comment: Ok, is it this API: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ ? I I klick on your hyperlink I just get `http://json%20api%20wordpress/` in the url field and the error message: Website not available.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Sry for the wrong link, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok. And how do I get the title, autor, date and link of a post? Is it something like: `item.title` `item.author`?

Comment: And is there also a link to the images which are included in the post?

Comment: just print "item", and you'll see

Comment: I printed `item` now I get the JSON code. But how can I print out the title of the JSON as an String?

Comment: item is a dictionary. So to get the title of the first item just use item["title"].